# How to fix this NameError: name 'clf' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Feature Selection --> Random Forest
def feature_importance(clf):
    # Relative Importance (Features)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    # Get Feature Importance from the classifier
    feature_importance = clf.feature_importances_
    # Normalize The Features
    feature_importance = 100.0 * (feature_importance / feature_importance.max())
    # Sort Features and Creat Horizontal Bar Plot
    sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importance)
    pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0]) + .5
    pl.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
    pl.barh(pos, feature_importance[sorted_idx], align='center', color='#0033CC')
    pl.yticks(pos, np.asanyarray(df.columns.tolist())[sorted_idx])
    pl.xlabel("Relative Importance")
    pl.title("Variable Importance - Random Forest")
    pl.show()


clf_NB = GaussianNB()
clf_SVC = SVC()
clf_RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)

algorithms = [clf_NB,clf_SVC,clf_RF]

for model in algorithms:
    print("\n")
    print("==============================")
    print("Model: {}".format(model.__class__.__name__))
    print("==============================")
    print("\n")
    print("**********************************************************")
    print("**Training**")
    print("Data Size:",len(X_train))
    # Fit model to training data
    train_classifier(model, X_train, y_train)

    # Predict on training set and compute F1 score
    predict_labels(model, X_train, y_train)

    #Predict on Testing Data
    print("**********************************************************")
    print("**Testing**")
    print("Data Size:",len(X_test))
    predict_labels(model, X_test, y_test)

    if clf == clf_RF:
        print("\n")
        feature_importance(clf_RF)
```

I believe that the 'clf' is declared in the above code. But I don't understand why I'm still getting this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-bcd9b039b6a5> in <module>
     26     predict_labels(model, X_test, y_test)
     27 
---> 28     if clf == clf_RF:
     29         print("\n")
     30         feature_importance(clf_RF)

NameError: name 'clf' is not defined
```

Comment: *"I believe that the 'clf' is declared in the above code."* Where? Where are you declaring it?

Comment: Is it def feature_importance(clf) ? Please don't be mad. I'm trying to run a code I found online to get some better understanding

Comment: `clf` is defined as a parameter of the `feature_importance()` function, but the error occurs outside of that function.

Comment: Check the scope of the variable w.r.t. your function and indentation

Comment: That `clf` only exists inside the `feature_importance` function.

Comment: okay.. where do I need to declare it? I'm following a full code and I'm stuck in this part.

Comment: We can't tell you where to declare it because you haven't told us what the code is supposed to do. Part of providing a [mcve] is explaining the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clf` is only defined within the scope of the `feature_importance` method. The value of `clf` isn't stored anywhere outside this method, so once you leave the method, it's as if `clf` never existed.

It appears as though you want to check if the value of `model` you're currently iterating over is `clf_RF`, going by your loop. If you change your if statement to check for `model == clf_RF`, the code should work as intended.

Comment: It worked now! Thank you. You clearly explained it as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like clf is declared in the arguments of the function feature_importance but where you are using it is out of scope.

Comment: Understood it now. Thank you